# logrotate gives error while executing /etc/cron.daily/logrotate command

Tags: centos, logrotate

I am using logrotate . I am using following structure for /etc/logrotae.conf  :

```
/var/log/messages {
 daily
    size=1G
    rotate 1
    postrotate
            service rsyslog restart > /dev/null
    endscript
rotate 4 }
```

while I am executing following command :

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

I got the following error :

```
error: /etc/logrotate.conf:33 duplicate log entry for /var/log/messages
```

I am using centOS . Can any out help me to figure it out ?

Answer (score 0):

Logrotate is using /etc/logrotate.conf and /etc/logrrotate.d as source for configuration.

Search for all rules, you certainly have 2 rules matching /var/log/messages